# Analyze MAP data and validate it in time

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I have data about car mileage history on a map. Which looks like this:

```
{
  "999": {
    created: 1698399814, // UNIX TIME
    mileage: 120000,        
  }
  "898": {
    created: 1698399772, // UNIX TIME
    mileage: 220000,
  }
}
```

The KEY of a map will probably be when data was collected, the VALUEs are:

- "created" which means when data was created (e.g. I collected it today but it was created in 2022)
- "mileage" is the number of mileage the car has at that moment

I need to calculate if the data are not suspicious. Which means mileage is not going down in time. In the example above it's clearly that first data with mileage 220000 was created and after that 120000 was created which looks suspicious.

How can I easily determine this?

What I tried and works but it's kind of ugly:

```
const historyArray = [];
const historyMap = new Map();
historyMap .set('999',  {
    createdAt: 1698399814, // UNIX TIME
    mileage: 120000,        
  });
historyMap .set('898',  {
    createdAt: 1698399772, // UNIX TIME
    mileage: 220000,        
  });
for (const item of historyMap.values()) {
   historyArray.push(item);
}

const sortedA = [...historyArray].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt).map((item) => item.createdAt);
const sortedB = [...historyArray].sort((a, b) => a.mileage - b.mileage).map((item) => item.createdAt);

const suspicious = sortedA.join() === sortedB.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to sort the data into `createdAt` ascending order. Then all you need to do is to validate that each `mileage` value in the array is lower than the next.

Here's a working example of this pattern:

```js
// arrange data:
const historyMap = new Map();
historyMap.set('999', { createdAt: 1698399814, mileage: 120000 });
historyMap.set('898', { createdAt: 1698399772, mileage: 220000 });

// function to validate that the mileage values always increase as time goes on
const isValid = arr => {
  return arr.every((v, i) => {
    var nextIndex = i + 1;
    return nextIndex < arr.length ? v.mileage <= arr[nextIndex].mileage : true;
  });
}

// create an array of objects from the Map, sorted by date
const sortedArray = [...historyMap].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt < b.createdAt ? 1 : -1).map(x => x[1]);
const historyIsValid = isValid(sortedArray);

console.log(historyIsValid);
```